# why Javascript "typeerror"

Tags: javascript

This executes to produce the correct result, and the Chrome debugger says there were no exceptions:

```
var x = new Foo().bar().baz();
```

but this goes off into space and never completes, and the Chrome debugger says although bar() executed correctly, it then throws a "typeerror" exception and never gets to the specified function when it attempts to invoke baz():

```
var x = new Foo();
x = x.bar().baz();
```

It looks to me like they're functionally identical. Why do they behave differently?

Comment: Does `.bar()` return `this`?  What does the first one do when you do this: `var x = (new Foo()).bar().baz();`?  More of the definition and implementation of `Foo`, `.bar()` and `.baz()` would make it more obvious to us what is going on.  A simple jsFiddle would make it all clear for us to examine.

Comment: Both cases execute without issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/fsD4A/4 I think you need to give us a more concrete example of what you are using for `Foo` `bar` and `baz`. Or how about showing us a jsfiddle that reproduces this issue?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question - and boy do I feel stoopid! Sorry. Short answer to "Why do they behave differently?"-  **they don't**.

Motivated by having others try the same thing but get different results, I pondered my problem further and eventually discovered  ...a typo! The original name of the function I modeled as "baz()" was a verbose string in camelcase, and an ell ('l') of the wrong case had crept in.

It turned out debuggers were a red herring. (I used them only to trace execution and display error messages, but not to evaluate anything or simulate an environment.)

Hopefully I would have found the real problem much sooner if the error messages had been more straightforward. The Chrome debugger reported the throwing of a "typeerror", and Firebug reported an "invalid scope variable", neither of which clued me to look for a typo in a function name.

Lesson learned: don't post a question after midnight:-)

Answer (score 5):

Seems to be related to the Chrome debugger:

```
function Foo(){}

Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
  return this;
}

Foo.prototype.baz = function() {
  return 'baz';
}

var x = new Foo().bar().baz();
console.log(x); // baz
```

As expected (Firefox, IE, Chrome).

#### Edit

And also:

```
var x = new Foo();
x = x.bar().baz()
console.log(x); // baz
```

The two sets of code are functionally the same.

Comment: So what environment is your example succeeding in?

Comment: @nrabinowitz This will work in _Console_ and in a `<script>`

Comment: My reading of the spec suggests that `new` doesn't bind more tightly than `.`, but I'm not super confident of that. I'm too lazy and beer-laden to try it at the moment. *edit* actually now I think I'm wrong.

Comment: It's evaluated left to right, per [§ 11.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2): `new MemberExpression Arguments` -> `CallExpression . IdentifierName` -> `CallExpression . IdentifierName` -> `CallExpression`. Or something like that.

Comment: OP has already said that `new Foo().bar().baz()` works as he expects it to. You haven't addressed the code that is causing an error for him and I don't see how this is an answer to his question.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer. The two lots of code are functionally equivalent, any difference is due to the Chrome debugger (if there really is such a difference).

Answer (score 2):

You need parentheses:

```
var x = (new Foo()).bar().baz();
```

Otherwise, the `new` statement is applying to the return value of `Foo().bar().baz()`, all of which will be executed before there's any attempted instantiation.

**Update**: It has been brought to my attention that this is, as they say, *wrong*. But I think the comments are interesting, so I'm not deleting the answer.

Comment: Right - the `.` operator binds more tightly than `new`

Comment: -1 That may be required for the Chrome debugger, but it is not required in ECMAScript.

Comment: So who's right, @pointy, or RobG?

Comment: @AdamRackis—see my answer, tested in Firefox, IE and Chrome. Not really interested in digging out the relevant part of the spec, I suspect it starts about here: [§11 Expressions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11).

Comment: @AdamRackis I think RobG is right here - it's not the `.` operator that's interesting vs. `new`, it's the function call (the parentheses after the constructor name).

Comment: @Pointy if `a = foo.bar` then yes `new foo.bar()` is like `new a`, but when you use `new foo().bar`, the `()`change the behaviour and it makes a new instance of `foo` first..

Comment: Yeah, looks like @RobG is correct. But if the OP's code examples are correct, then he *does* need the parens, which suggests that we might need to see his code - not sure I buy the debugger argument.

Comment: Also - re-reading the question seems to indicate that it's the *second* statement that fails, not the first. Which renders my answer totally off-base :(.